# In UWP, can I check if a StorageFolder is a parent of another StorageFolder?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, directory, filesystems

I have an app that recursively manage files and folders in a [`StorageFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder?view=winrt-22621) picked by users (using `FolderPicker`). Now users may add multiple folders into the managing list. However right now my app does not know if user may pick a parent folder of another picked one which would cause duplicate files. For example they can pick `D:\test\subfolder` and then pick `D:\test` (or vice versa).

My question is, giving two `StorageFolder` instances, can I request an operation that detects if an instance is a subfolder of the other? I cannot see any obvious method in the API documentation page.

---

After typing the question, I thought of a workaround that is listing the contents of each folder and see if any child matches the other. I am not even sure if I can do this and if possible I would prefer not doing this because a folder content maybe very large (possibly the entire partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be able to use [StorageFolder.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.path?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-storagefolder-path), to get the path of the two instances and then based on that you can determine if they are sub-routed, example:

```
var file1 = @"D:\test\";
var file2 = @"D:\test\subfolder";


if(file1.StartsWith(file2) || file2.StartsWith(file1)){
    Console.WriteLine("Folders are subrouted");    
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the way. At first I thought UWP apps are sandboxed and I should not reliably get access to the `Path` but that was just my assumption.

Comment: @LukeVo If fbv's solution solves the issue, you could accept it.